# wait for service:Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to launch the my_world.launch I am facing this problem.

Code for my_world.launch is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<launch>
 <arg name="debug" default="false" />
 <arg name="gui" default="false" />
 <arg name="pause" default="true" />
 <arg name="world" default="$(find my_gazebo)/world/empty_world.world" />
 <include file = "$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world)" />
  <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
  <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
  <arg name="paused" value="$(arg pause)" />
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />

 </include>

</launch>
```

empty_world.world code is here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <sdf version="1.6">
      <world name="default">
       <include>
         <uri>model://sun</uri>
       </include>
       <include>
         <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
       </include>
      </world>
    </sdf>
```

I am facing this problem:

```
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch my_gazebo my_world.launch
... logging to /home/glv/.ros/log/09788d08-d7b3-11e8-a35c-9822ef7fc42b/roslaunch-VaraPrasad-4041.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://VaraPrasad:44853/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [4058]
[ INFO] [1540402702.643569843]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1540402702.644173326]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1540402702.908795885, 0.024000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1540402702.963873717, 0.078000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
^C[gazebo-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ 
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch my_gazebo my_world.launch
... logging to /home/glv/.ros/log/09788d08-d7b3-11e8-a35c-9822ef7fc42b/roslaunch-VaraPrasad-4309.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://VaraPrasad:37831/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [4326]
[ INFO] [1540402736.589018029]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1540402736.589433988]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

I am using Ros Kinetic version , Ubuntu 16.04 and Gazebo 9

Thanks In Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306612/wait-for-service:service-%5B/gazebo/set_physics_properties%5D-has-not-been-advertised,-waiting.../) by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you copy and paste the terminal output instead of a screenshot please ? It's not searchable like that.

For your issue, you launch Gazebo with `pause` set to `true` so you son't start the service, this will start it :

```
roslaunch my_gazebo my_world.launch pause:=false
```

The proper solution is to modify this value in your launch file. Moreover you tried with `verbose :=true`, yet you didn't defined the arg `verbose` in your launch file so it's basically doing nothing.

Finally I don't know if you are aware of it but you also set `gui` to `false` so you won't have the `Gazebo GUI` with your launch file, set it to `true` in your launch file to launch it or simply type the command `$gzclient` after your roslaunch.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2018-10-24**:
Thank you **Mr.Delb.** Your answer is worked for me. Basically I don't have much idea about this I am trying to launch my robot(mobile robot that created in gazebo) in gazebo with roslaunch and also I want to control it by teleop_keys. Any suggestions regarding arguments?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-24**:
Good, you can mark the answer as correct too please.
For your question you can create a new one if you have an issue but I would suggest to look at this [gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch)